# Fetch a page with cookies using Python requests library

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I'm just studying the requests library(http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/),
and got a problem on how to fetch a page with cookies using requests.

for example:

```
url2= 'https://passport.baidu.com'
parsedCookies={'PTOKEN': '412f...', 'BDUSS': 'hnN2...', ...} #Sorry that the cookies value is replaced by ... for instance of privacy
req = requests.get(url2, cookies=parsedCookies)
text=req.text.encode('utf-8','ignore')
f=open('before.html','w')
f.write(text)
f.close()
req.close()
```

when I use the codes above to fetch the page, it just saves the login page to 'before.html' instead of logined page, it refers that actually I haven't logged in successfully.

But if I use URLlib2 to fetch the page, it works properly as expected.

```
parsedCookies="PTOKEN=412f...;BDUSS=hnN2...;..." #Different format but same content with the aboved cookies
req = urllib2.Request(url2)
req.add_header('Cookie', parsedCookies)
ret = urllib2.urlopen(req)
f=open('before_urllib2.html','w')
f.write(ret.read())
f.close()
ret.close()
```

When I use these codes, it saves the logined page in `before_urllib2.html`.

--

Are there any mistakes in my code?
Any reply would be grateful.

Comment: Why not use a session here and have `requests` take care of the cookies for you?

Comment: And you can use `req.content` to get the original encoded text. And encoding unicode to UTF8 *never* needs to use `'ignore'`, UTF-8 can handle all codepoints.

Comment: Thx to your reply. First, in my code, the cookies is passed from outside, I can only do like this. Second, req.content works well, thx for reminding. But I used to call encode() without 'ignore', but it raised an exception, like "UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\uXXXX' in position XX". So I add 'ignore', do you know why?

Comment: What version of Requests are you using?

Comment: The latest one downloaded from github. Filename is requests-master.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Session object to get what you desire:

```
url2='http://passport.baidu.com'
session = requests.Session()  # create a Session object 
cookie = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(parsedCookies) 
session.cookies.update(cookie) # set the cookies of the Session object

req = session.get(url2, headers=headers,allow_redirects=True)
```

If you use the requests.get function, it doesn't send cookies for the redirected page. Instead, if you use the Session().get function, it will maintain and send cookies for all http requests, this is what the concept "session" exactly means.

Let me try to elaborate to you what happens here:

When I sent cookies to `http://passport.baidu.com/center` and set the parameter allow_redirects as false, the returned status code is 302 and one of the headers of the response is 'location': '/center?_t=1380462657' (This is a dynamic value generated by server, you can replace it with what you get from server):

```
url2= 'http://passport.baidu.com/center'
req = requests.get(url2, cookies=parsedCookies, allow_redirects=False)
print req.status_code # output 302
print req.headers
```

But when I set the parameter allow_redirects as True, it still doesn't redirect to the page (`http://passport.baidu.com/center?_t=1380462657`) and the server return the login page. The reason is that the requests.get doesn't send cookies for the redirected page, here is `http://passport.baidu.com/center?_t=1380462657`, so we can login successfully. That is why we need the Session object.

If I set `url2 = http://passport.baidu.com/center?_t=1380462657`, it will return the page you want. One solution is use the above code to get the dynamic location value and form a path to you account like `http://passport.baidu.com/center?_t=1380462657` , then you can get the desired page.

```
url2= 'http://passport.baidu.com' + req.headers.get('location')
req = session.get(url2, cookies=parsedCookies, allow_redirects=True )
```

But this is cumbersome, so when dealing with cookies, Session object do excellent job for us!

Comment: 'https://passport.baidu.com/v2/api/?login' doesn't work, nor 'https://passport.baidu.com/v2/?login'.

Comment: Actually, urllib2 works well with 'https://passport.baidu.com/' or 'https://passport.baidu.com/v2/?login'

Comment: No. It still saves the login page.

Comment: Thanks very much to your reply, and I learn a lot. I use session but remove headers from session.get(): req=session.get(url2, allow_redirects=True) . But it still doesn't work properly. Do I need to set any headers?

Comment: Headers are optional, I just used it as a test originally. I guess you may have not enough cookies. In my case, all my cookies are:'USERNAMETYPE', 'STOKEN', 'SAVEUSERID', 'PTOKEN', 'mkey', 'HOSUPPORT', 'Hm_lvt_90056b3f84f90da57dc0f40150f005d5', 'Hm_lpvt_90056b3f84f90da57dc0f40150f005d5', 'HISTORY_E', 'BDUSS', 'BAIDUID'.

Comment: My cookies is as follows: BDUSS;PTOKEN;STOKEN;SAVEUSERID;USERNAMETYPE;NEWUSER;HISTORY_E;  I think it's enough because it works well with URLlib2.

Comment: That is strange, but it works for me, I guess this is package dependent, but, only a guess:).

Comment: Thanks any way, it's so weird.